# VS Code how to add gradle sub module

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, gradle

I'm a Java developer. Currently I'm using IntelliJ. I am happy with it, but I want to try a new IDE. So I have chosen Visual Studio Code.

I want to create a Spring Boot application in Gradle as a multi-module project. My project exists already, but I want to add a new sub-module. In IntelliJ there exists a menu item to add a new module, but I can't find any equal option in VSCode. Should I really create the folder structure on my own or is there a plugin which can do this for me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you download the [Gradle for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-gradle) extension?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.
Here is a list of my extension :
Debugger for Java
Extension Pack for Java
Gradle Extensionpack
Gradle for Java
Project Manager

In IntelliJ there exists an option in the menu to add a new module.
So IntelliJ creates a folder (with the name of the sub module) and creates the source an test folders.
I'v not found any equal option in vs code

Comment: As i am facing the same problem, I think the question of the OP is quite clear. So the community seems to have no answer or there is no solution at the moment for VSCode with Java